# Setting state of checkbox to 'check' based on database record or previous edit state?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm struggling with this and Google has failed me!

In the code below, everything works fine. But if other validation rules on the form fail, i'd like the changed states of these checkboxes to be remembered.

In other parts of my form, i'm able to use the 'old' variable to retrieve the previous input.

```
{{ old('Bathrooms', optional($prop ?? null)->a_baths) }}
```

I think the problem i'm having is because the 'tags' attribute inthe request is an array, so is it also an array within the Old variables? I need to somehow combine both checks..

```
<div class="form-row row mt-1">
<label class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right" for="tags">Features:</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    @php $currentTags = $prop->tags->pluck('id'); @endphp   

    @foreach($tags as $tag)
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" 
            name="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]"
            value="{{ $tag->id }}" 
                @if(in_array($tag->id, $currentTags->toArray())) checked @endif
            id="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]">{{ $tag->name }}</label>
    </div>
    @endforeach 
    @error('tags') 
    <p class="font-weight-light text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: Could you try the following: `@php $currentTags = old('tags', $prop->tags->pluck('id')->toArray()); @endphp` and `@if(in_array($tag->id, $currentTags)) checked @endif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following changes should work for you:

Change

```
@php $currentTags = $prop->tags->pluck('id'); @endphp
```

to

```
@php $currentTags = old('tags', $prop->tags->pluck('id')->toArray()); @endphp
```

And

```
if(in_array($tag->id, $currentTags->toArray())) checked @endif
```

to

```
@if(in_array($tag->id, $currentTags)) checked @endif
```

You can use the `old()` helper to set `$currenTags` to the selected tags of `$prop` by default and the selected tags when the form is submitted otherwise.

The finished code:

```
<div class="form-row row mt-1">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right" for="tags">Features:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @php $currentTags = old('tags', $prop->tags->pluck('id')->toArray()); @endphp

        @foreach($tags as $tag)
            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
                       name="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]"
                       value="{{ $tag->id }}"
                       @if(in_array($tag->id, $currentTags)) checked @endif
                       id="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]">{{ $tag->name }}</label>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        @error('tags')
            <p class="font-weight-light text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BenHolmes Could you mark the question as answered if solved your issue.

Comment: Sorry, new to stackoverflow. Done now!